# TASM Can't locate .asm file Error: **Fatal** Command line: Can't locate file: filename.asm

Tags: tasm

Issue: when I run @ the command prompt `>tasm HelloWorld.asm` and BTW I am using TAB in entering the file name `HelloWorld.asm` so there is no typo. I get this fatal command line error:

> Turbo Assembler Version 4.1 Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland
>   International
>   
>   Assembling file: HelloWorld.asm
>   **Fatal** Command line: Can't locate file: HelloWorld.asm
>   Error messages: 1
>   Warning messages: None
>  Passes: 1
>   Remaining memory: 452k

Here is my `HelloWorld.asm`:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
;variablename type value or default initialization
dexter db "Hello World"

.code
start:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offeset dexter
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

end start
```

Request your kind help to know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009482/3512216) solve your problem?

Comment: @rkhb: I think you are right as I can reproduce that exact behavior.

Comment: @ali: Once renamed, tasm points that `offeset ` is a typo, and your string needs to be terminated by a `$` :)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar problem and found that keeping names less than 6-7 characters helps!

Comment: excellent answer but can you tell me what is logic behind this behaviour?

Comment: I can try @TAHASULTANTEMURI. Maybe the file system them only permitted small names. Hence the behavior

Comment: if this solves your problem, you should mark the answer as correct @TAHASULTANTEMURI

Answer (score 0):

```
.model tiny
.stack
.data
Message db "hola mundo$"
.code

start:
    mov dx,OFFSET Message
    mov ax, SEG Message
    mov ds,ax
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. My file path contained non-english terms, so I changed my path to English. That is solved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).