# Turbo Assembler Can't include macro library

Tags: windows, assembly, macros, tasm

Hoi chummers,

I could need some help with a project here.

I am currently learning Assembler (Tasm) by myself.
I wrote some simple 1-file programs to get used to the stuff.
Now I am at a point where I want to exclude some macros and other data from the code and put them into different files (so I can re-use them easy).

I am working with GUI Turbo Assembler x64 Version 3.0

It is a IDE that links and assembles stuff for you, so that I am not forced to open DOS-Box every time and write a lot of redundant lines.

Here is my .asm file:

```
INCLUDE progMacros              ;makrobibliothek einbinden
INCLUDE progConstanten          ;Konstanten einbinden (z.b. 4CH)

.Model  Small
.Stack  100h

.Data
variable    DB  6               ;normale Variable
INCLUDE progDaten               ;bibliothek mit variablen

.Code  
Start:
   segmentPreloader
   textLoop    Hallo,variable
   textLoop    Ciao,1
   mov         ah,beenden
   int         EXEC
END Start
```

You see, a very basic and simple program that loops output of a string in a macro I defined @ progMacros

Now the problem:

Everytime I try and Assemble, it gives me this:

> Assembling file - C:\Users\ [private]
>   \Desktop\Assembler\bibliotheken\mainProg.asm
>   Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland
>   International
>      Assembling file:   mainProg.asm      **Fatal**
>   mainProg.asm(1) Can't locate file: progMacros
>   Error messages:    1
>   Warning messages:  None 
> Passes:            1 
> Remaining memory:  469k

[note i won't give you my username in windows]

Here's my first troubleshooting:

1) Renamed all files and directives proper as seen in a tutorial
(f.e. macros.bib and progData.dat)
2) shortened the file names, moved whole project to C:\
3) specified "iPath" with the path to the folder where the files are
(btw: they are all in the same folder mainProg.asm is in)

I dunno what else to do, this is frustrating, Assembler is much fun, and on Linux it was super easy to write some sample code.... But I want to code on windows too!

Please, oh mighty community of SOF, help me out of this misery

_clockw0rk

Comment: Under MS-DOS file names are limited to 8.3 (8 characters and 3 character extension). _progConstanten_ and _progMacros_ exceed the file name lengths. Possibly TASM requires file names follow the same convention.

Comment: Good point, and was one of the "classic" errors I stumbled upon googeling, so i renamed the file to "kek" and "kek.bib", but nothing helped...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the files aren't in the same directory as your assembler files, or if they are in another directory they haven't been specified on the include path. You can specify paths to include with the `/I` option in TASM.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, they are in the same directory. When I get home from work today, I will play around with the /I option a bit and try manual Assembling. Do you have a good link for Windows TASM assembling and linking maybe? Much thanks for your time -cW

Comment: Although for a slightly newer version, the TASM documentation here is a good source: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009482/3512216). Try to rename `progMacros` to `macros.inc` (or any name with max. 8 letters, but with dot and a three-letters-extension such as `.asm` or `.inc`) and to include with `INCLUDE macros.inc`.

Comment: I recommend you contact the author of the GUI. I played around, and hit the same issue you did. regular 8.3 file names with extension .inc and .asm didn't even work. It wouldn't even find WINDOWS.INC that came with the product. Also noticed it doesn't even allow editing of files that don't have ASM extension. I think it is related to how the files are accessed within the DosBox session it creates. It acts like the only file that might be present is the one you are compiling and nothing else.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Your link to the documentation is for the right version. The [GUI Turbo Assembler x64 Version 3.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086/?source=navbar) includes Turbo Assembler 5.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved in version GUI Turbo Assembler 3.0.1.

Comment: @JF The statement `This issue is resolved in version GUI Turbo Assembler 3.0.1` is the actual answer. The link is to the program, not sure what other information you'd expect to be placed into the answer besides embedding the program itself. This is _NOT_ a link only answer.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thank you for your suggestion; I have removed the link

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the Macro library couldnt be found when i dragged a program into Dosbox.
So I opened Dosbox, mounted the whole drive as C: and set the paths manually and it worked fine.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34941560)