# Assembler program can't open and read a text file properly. It just exits without doing anything

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm trying to open a text file, which is in the same directory as my .asm file. The text file contains one short sentence as a message and can contain up to 200 characters. The program should read the message from the .txt-file and then use the sentence read for further work. The problem is that it just exits without doing anything. I'm compiling with TASM. Here' s the code:

```
JUMPS
masm
model small
.data
handle  dw  0 
filename     db 'the_message.txt',0
point_fname dd  filename

string  db  200 dup (" ")
point_buffer dd string

errorMes db  0ah,0dh,'Not allowed any more!','$'
mes    db   0ah,0dh,'Type 1 to crypt, type 2 to decrypt!','$'
mes1   db   0ah,0dh,'Crypted one time ','$'
mes2   db   0ah,0dh,'Crypted two times ','$'
mes3   db   0ah,0dh,'Decrypted','$'
count  db   0
.stack  256
.code
main:
;open
mov ax,@data 
mov ds,ax 
mov al,0 
lds dx,point_fname 
mov ah,3dh 
int 21h
jc  exit 
mov [handle],ax
;read
mov bx,[handle]
mov cx,200
lds dx,point_buffer
mov ah,3fh 
int 21h
jc  exit
mov bp,ax 
nop
;close
mov ah,3eh 
int 21h
jc  exit
nop
;Now crypt and decrypt
jmp ask
crypt1: 
;test
cmp count,0
jg  crypt2

xor ax,ax   
mov cx,bp   
mov si,0    
go1:        
add string[si],1    
inc si  
loop    go1 
inc count
;print on the screen
mov cx,bp
mov si,0
mov ah,09h
lea dx,mes1
int 21h
jmp show


crypt2: 
;test
cmp count,1
jg  notAllowed

xor ax,ax 
mov cx,bp   
mov si,0    
go2:        
add string[si],2    
inc si  
loop    go2 
inc count
;print on the screen
mov cx,bp
mov si,0
mov ah,09h
lea dx,mes2
int 21h
jmp show


decrypt2:   
;test
cmp count,2
jl  decrypt1

xor ax,ax   
mov cx,bp   
mov si,0    
goDecr2:        
sub string[si],2    
inc si  
loop    goDecr2 
dec count
;print on the screen
mov cx,bp
mov si,0
mov ah,09h
lea dx,mes3
int 21h
jmp show


decrypt1:   
;test
cmp count,1
jl  notAllowed

xor ax,ax   
mov cx,bp   
mov si,0    
goDecr1:        
sub string[si],1    
inc si  
loop    goDecr1 
dec count
;print on the screen
mov cx,bp
mov si,0
mov ah,09h
lea dx,mes3
int 21h
;jmp show

show:
mov ah,02h  
mov dl,string[si]
int 21h
inc si
loop    show
ask:
mov ah,09h
lea dx,mes
int 21h

mov ah, 01h 
int 21h

cmp al, 31h
je  crypt1
jmp decrypt2

notAllowed:
mov ah,09h
lea dx,errorMes
int 21h
;jmp exit
exit: 
mov ax,4c00h 
int 21h 
end main
```

Comment: The string "the_message.txt" is too long. MS-DOS only accepts [8.3-filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). Also, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24009482/3512216).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works!  You are great!